# Just cloned the flutter repo, is it installing the correct dart sdk?

Tags: flutter

I just cloned the flutter repo in my home directory and added `$HOME/flutter/bin` to my `PATH`.

When I run `flutter --help` I get the following error:

```sh
$ flutter --help
Building flutter tool...
/home/noib3/flutter/bin/internal/shared.sh: line 24: /home/noib3/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart: No such file or directory
Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (9 tries left)
^C
```

The reported error is that `~/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart` doesn't exist, which isn't true, the dart sdk is there.

I then tried to execute the line 24 in `~/flutter/bin/internal/shared.sh` manually:

```sh
$ ~/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart __deprecated_pub upgrade --verbosity=normal --no-precompile
Failed to execute process '/home/noib3/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart'. Reason:
The file '/home/noib3/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart' does not exist or could not be executed.
```

Having ruled out the `does not exist` option, I'm left with `could not be executed`. I'm not sure what's going wrong here. Is it installing the right dark sdk for my OS? I'm using Linux, specifically NixOS.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Go inside the flutter/bin folder and delete the cache folder.

If that doesn't work, I recommend deleting it and downloading it again. Maybe restarting your computer after adding it to path.